# MC - Triggered Sends vs Journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, triggered-send

**Summary**

I'm trying to decide whether to use either triggered sends or a journey reading from Salesforce data, but since I'm not very experienced, I don't really see the pitfalls of either.

**Use Case**

Automate email reminders to the contacts associated to an opportunity when the closed date is getting closer.

**Possible solutions**

1. Create a Mkt Cloud Journey which feeds from Salesforce Opportunities, filters by date and sends the emails accordingly.
2. Create a Triggered send which... does the same thing :)

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Journey based on data synchronized into the marketing cloud for the scenario you describe.

**Reasoning:**

- **Triggered Send:** Works but requires developer know-how and deployment if you want to change the date criteria.
- **Salesforce data based entry:** currently date filters for those are limited to fixed dates, so you can't use criteria like "x days before"
- **Data Extension/Automation (Marketing Cloud data) based entry:** easy to use drag and drop filtering with full date capabilities on date criteria. This makes it easier for you to change filter criteria when you have to optimize or bugfix the journey. Also, only entry events based on Marketing Cloud data are supported for Journey Entry testing. Last, but not least: Data is easier to use for personalization in your Emails as the field name structure is less complex.